# OktaUserClient.ForgotPassword returns null in Okta C# sdk

Tags: okta

I am using Okta C# sdk. when I use Okta userclient.forgotpassword then it sending reset password mail to user but as a response it returns null. 
Can anyone help how will I sure that it has sent reset email to user?

Answer (score 1):

Dinesh,

This is the expected behavior: when you specify sendEmail=true with the Okta API, the response is empty if the email was sent (otherwise, you get an exception). 
If you specify sendEmail=false, then the response provides the unique password reset url.

There can be a multitude of reasons why your users do not receive the password reset email that are beyond Okta's control, but if you get a null response, you should expect the email has indeed been successfully sent by Okta.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Raphael for explaining this.

Comment: Can you help me on this too?                                         
I am using Okta C# sdk for development. I have created some custom user profile attributes in the Okta. I am able to create user and save values in custom attributes.
But as I saw that when you update profile data you have to provide all the details again. If you provide specific attributes value then sets null for other attributes. So how can I update only one or two attributes so that other should not change?